# Run method based on cached value availability

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, request

I have the following scenario:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "foo") == nil {
     asyncRequest() { foo in
         myMethod(foo)
     }
} else {
      myMethod(foo)
}
```

I am basically checking if I have the `foo` variable cached at the moment. If it isn't, I get it from the server, but if I have it, I call the method directly.

Is there a better practice to avoid having to use an if-else statement here? (e.g. something that will allow me to call `myMethod(foo)` only once)

Answer (score 0):

That seems about right, just be mindful that bool(forKey:) will always return a bool, not an optional. For that you should use value(forKey:). You could also do something like this

```
var foo: Bool? {
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "foo") as? Bool
}

func assignValue() {
    guard let foo = foo else {
        // your async call here
        return
    }
    myMethod(foo)
```

}

Comment: Oh, don't worry about the UserDefaults value. I wrote a fast example, it's not really the case I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "foo") == nil {
     group.enter()

     asyncRequest() { foo in
         UserDefaults.standard.set(bool: foo, forKey: "foo")
         group.leave()
     }
} 

group.notify(queue: .main) {
      let foo = UserDefaults.standard.set(bool: foo, forKey: "foo")
      myMethod(foo)
}
```

The idea is that `group.notify()` will be triggered in both cases.